# Showing Ajax loader after website fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show ajax loader when my website is fully loaded. i'm using the following codes but it's not working.

```
<div style="display:none" id="divloader"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>

$(function() {
$(".changepass").click(function() {
    $("#divloader").show();
    $(".block1").load("index.php", function(){ $("#divloader").hide();    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I've fixed all typo error/ syntax error . But It's not working yet. Is there anyone who has working example ?

Comment: There's a typo error: `$("#dvloader").show();` should be `$("#divloader").show();`

Comment: Your javascript code should be inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: Show the html. Your loader will show if you click on something with class="changepass" which likely should be an ID. Also loading.gif needs to be available to show

Comment: I've corrected all syntax, but it's not working yet. Do you have any working example ?

Comment: Do console.log statements at each point work? Is the path to loading.gif correct? The `#divloader` div should  not  be within `.block1`.

Answer (score 0):

syntax error in your code

at this line `$("#dvloader").show();` use `$("#divloader").show();`

```
<div style="display:none" id="divloader"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
$(".changepass").click(function() {
    $("#divloader").show();
    $(".block1").load("views/index.php", function(){ $("#divloader").hide();    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I've corrected sysntax but It's not working. Kindly can you show any working example ?

Comment: @EbrahimKhalil is it typo error again? your code is not inside a `<script>` tag